# Spring boot Keycloak blocking not configured url also

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I' learning Spring boot with Keycloak as security system.

Java 11 with keycloak 11.0.1

I've uploaded the project at https://github.com/ajeetkumarv/myemr
and following this tutorial of 3 links. first being https://www.thomasvitale.com/introducing-keycloak-identity-access-management/

access works perfectly for configured urls `/books` and `/managers` but when I send post request through `send.html` to `/customer/save` it says `Forbidden`

My requirement is it should be allowed. do i need to configure a public user for this, how to configure that?

Quick snap of code

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/books").hasAnyRole("Member", "Librarian")
            .antMatchers("/manager").hasRole("Librarian")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Two things to mention here;

- Order is important in HttpSecurity configuration
- You are calling super.configure(http);

Order is important which means if you anyRequest().authenticated() before your other lines that it will have higher priority. And you are calling super.configure() before your configuration where `anyRequest().authenticated()` exists (as much as I remember). So check your code by removing super.configure() line (instead, configure lines in your class which you need from your parent)